# Docker ADD does not copy into the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have several files in a directory on the host machine which I am trying to copy to the container and also have some run commands inside my docker-compose.

The first set up until the crowd section stats woks fine, but anything from the crown jar down just fails and doesn't work. I tried to run the manial docker cp command to copy the files from host to the container and that works. Can someone please shed some light on this?

This is a part of my Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
USER root
COPY server.xml conf/server.xml
RUN chmod 660 conf/server.xml
USER root
ADD tomcat.keystore /usr/local/tomcat/
RUN chmod 644 tomcat.keystore
RUN chown root:staff /usr/local/tomcat/tomcat.keystore

ADD crowd-auth-filter-1.0.0.jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/
ADD crowd-filter.properties /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/
RUN chmod 644 crowd-filter.properties
ADD web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/
RUN /usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
RUN /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the error is?

Comment: No error if I run docker-compose up --force-recreate -d

Comment: If I build  docker-compose build guacamole (service name is guacamole) then I get: ERROR: Service 'guacamole' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder641152197/usr/local/tomcat: no such file or directory

Comment: Is it possible to see the output of `docker build`? Judging from the error message in your previous comment I can't understand why it would make it as far as you say in the question.

Comment: Replaced the line with COPY crowd-auth-filter-1.0.0.jar /webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib --> It now adds the file to the destination but also removes all the files in the destination directory

Comment: It says build output is too long to add as a comment here :-(

Comment: It now copies them over but at the same time deletes all existing files inside the destination directory. This is what I changed my copy commands to:

`ADD ./lib/crowd-auth-filter-1.0.0.jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/crowd-auth-filter-1.0.0.jar`
`ADD ./lib/crowd-filter.properties /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/crowd-filter.properties`
`RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/crowd-filter.properties`
`ADD web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/web.xml`